# Cleaning touchpad and now wont work

Tags: touchpad, cleaning

My laptop was kind of dirty s i decided to clean it with a Lysol wipe, (Mind you I wringed it out)
and now everything but my touch pad works.
Like the touch pad will be fine for 20 seconds but will stop working.
And it has no pattern or anything it just stops working.
I tried touchpad videos for like 30 minutes so i hope that didnt damage anything by me keeping it on and i let it st in a fan for 30 minutes and it still wont work.
Help

Comment: Try cleaning off residue with a very clean damp cloth.

Comment: **Slightly** damp with **water**.

Comment: Try wiping with a clean cloth slightly dampened (not saturated) with distilled water, and then with another clean cloth dampened with 99% alcohol (ethanol, n-propanol or isopropanol), Then let dry as you did before, Assuming there was no electrolytic corrosion from Lysol that leaked into the machine, that should fix it. (Personally., I prefer using a mouse, and wouldn't notice a dead trackpad.)